# Make jquery script update on window resize?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have made a jquery script that relies on variables for viewport width and viewport height.
This is the  script with the `viewportwidth` and `viewportheight` variables, stored in its own document:

```
var viewportwidth,viewportheight;"undefined"!=typeof window.innerWidth?(viewportwidth=window.innerWidth,viewportheight=window.innerHeight):"undefined"!=typeof document.documentElement&&"undefined"!=typeof document.documentElement.clientWidth&&0!=document.documentElement.clientWidth?(viewportwidth=document.documentElement.clientWidth,viewportheight=document.documentElement.clientHeight):(viewportwidth=document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].clientWidth,viewportheight=document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].clientHeight);
```

Here is the script:

```
function kjør() {
    if ((viewportwidth / viewportheight) >= 1.33) {
            $('#redline').appendTo('body');
        $('#sitewrap').on('scroll', function(e) {
            if ($(this).scrollTop() > (viewportheight / 100 * 40)) {
                $('body').addClass('fix');
                $('#headerwrap').appendTo('body');
            } else {
                $('body').removeClass('fix');
                $('#headerwrap').appendTo('header');
            }
        $("#logo-top").css("opacity", 1 - $(this).scrollTop() / (viewportheight / 100 * 30));
        });
    } else {
        $('#headerwrap').appendTo('body');
        $('#redline').prependTo('#headerwrap');
        $('body').removeClass('fix');
    };
};
$(function() {
    kjør();
    $(window).resize(kjør());
});
```

As you can se at the bottom. I have tried making it so that the script will update  once `window` is resized. This doesnt work, however. The script will still use the `viewportwidth` and `viewportheight` that were established on pageload.
How can I make the script reevaluate viewport height and viewport width on window resize?

Comment: You're assigning the *result* of the `kjør()` function to the resize handler. You need to give it the function *reference* instead: `$(window).resize(kjør);`

Comment: Not exact duplicate but its answer will solve the problem

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is the line bellow:

```
 $(window).resize(kjør());
```

Change it to:

```
 $(window).resize(kjør);
```

When you use the sintax `function_name()` you are referencing the return value of the function, not the function itselfs.

Comment: Please don't answer such question. This is a very common mistake. Mark it as duplicate